# How to validate mime type ( is PDF for instance ) of both a file and a variable string?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a bunch of PDFs that were downloaded using a scraper. This scraper didn't check to see if the file was a JPG or a PDF so by default all of them were downloaded and saved with the '.pdf' extension. So, just to clarify all the files in the batch are .pdf. However, if I try to open them(The files that are not PDF but rather JPGs) via a server or locally I'm hit with an error.

My question. Is there a way with PHP to check and see if this file is a valid PDF? I would like to run all the URLs through a loop to check these files. There are hundreds of them and it would take hours upon hours to check.

Thanks

Comment: PDF's begin with `"%PDF"`

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because all Google searches direct me to something that is similar but not what I need. I feel like my question sums up what I need perfect. I have a bunch of files that are PDFs. However, some of those PDFs are JPGs that were accidentally saves as PDFs. I need to figure out which ones are which.

Comment: you say *"I would like to run all the URLs"* - can you elaborate on that? Edit: Never mind, [you said it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516408/check-to-see-if-pdf-is-actually-a-pdf-with-php#comment50994385_31516468). That's a whole different ballgame. *"This scraper didn't check to see if the file was a JPG or a PDF"* - Show us your present code.

Answer (score 2):

For local files (PHP 5.3+):

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
foreach (glob("path/to/files") as $filename) {
    if(finfo_file($finfo, $filename) === 'application/pdf') {
        echo "'{$filename}' is a PDF" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$filename}' is not a PDF" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

For remote files:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://path.to/your.pdf';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$results = split("\n", trim(curl_exec($ch)));
foreach($results as $line) {
    if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
            $parts = explode(":", $line);
            echo trim($parts[1]); // output: application/pdf
    }
}
```

Comment: No output on this script and I'm running a compatible PHP version.

Comment: If the PDF's were downloaded (as you mentioned) locally, the path is correct and `finfo` functions are present, this should work.

Comment: @smack-a-bro: You're not getting any output on anyone's scripts, so you are doing something wrong. Turn error reporting on and see what the problem is.

Comment: Note that the "remote files" example here is **blindly trusting the remote server** to tell you the real type of the file. This may or may not be appropriate depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Get MIME type of the file using function: [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

```
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, "PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE");
    finfo_close($finfo);
    echo $mimetype;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mimetype);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `finfo_file()` function

```
<?php
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
  $mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime_type = finfo_file($mime, "FILE-PATH");
  if($mime_type == "application/pdf")
    echo "file is pdf";
  else
    echo "file is not pdf";
  finfo_close($mime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you gotta check a mime signature of a file and sometimes of a variable. These are how you do both checkings:

```
$filename = '/path/to/my/file.pdf';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$file_is_pdf = function(string $filename) : bool {
    return mime_content_type($filename) === 'application/pdf';
};
$var_is_pdf = function(string $content) : bool {
    $mime_type_found = (new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME))->buffer($content);
    return $mime_type_found === 'application/pdf; charset=binary';
};
// Checks if a file contains a pdf signature.
var_dump($file_is_pdf($filename));

// Checks if a variable contains a pdf signature.
var_dump($var_is_pdf($content));
```