# How safe is wp_remote_get and writing to filesystem?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin which makes an API call to a book keeping service and I am integrating it with WooCommerce.

After the order is created I am using `woocommerce_email_order_details` hook to execute my API call using `$response = wp_remote_post( $post_url );`, where `$post_url` is modified so that it all works with the API.

Within this response is also a pdf which I am saving to a folder in the `uploads` folder using `WP_Filesystem()` API. This part looks like this:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $post_url );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
    $error_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response );
    return new WP_Error( $error_code, $error_message );
}

$body = json_decode( $response['body'] );

$pdf_link = esc_url( $body->order->pdf );
$pdf_name = esc_html( $body->order->order_number );

$pdf_get = wp_remote_get( $pdf_link );

if ( is_wp_error( $pdf_get ) ) {
    $error_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $pdf_get );
    $error_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $pdf_get );
    return new WP_Error( $error_code, $error_message );
}

$pdf_contents = $pdf_get['body'];

$pdf_name = 'order-' . $pdf_name . '.pdf';

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$new_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/orders/' . date( 'Y' ) . '/' . date( 'm' );

if ( ! file_exists( $new_dir ) ) {
    wp_mkdir_p( $new_dir );
}

global $wp_filesystem;
if ( empty( $wp_filesystem ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    WP_Filesystem();
}

$wp_filesystem->put_contents(
    $new_dir . '/' . $pdf_name,
    $pdf_contents,
    FS_CHMOD_FILE // predefined mode settings for WP files.
);
```

I've tested this with a live link on my local server and it all works.

One thing I don't think I can do is escape the contents of a pdf before saving it because that would break it. Even though this is something that the API of the book keeping service sends me, I don't want to assume anything and take it for granted.

What I am most interested in is: is this safe? Are there any possible vectors of attack here, because I wouldn't want to put my client at a risk.

Comment: you should check too if it's a valid pdf file...

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516408/check-to-see-if-pdf-is-actually-a-pdf-with-php ?

Comment: I would recommend using wp_handle_sideload() to get the file in the uploads directory.  (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload)

Comment: I want them in a separate folder, for easier extraction if need be :) But thanks.